# Page numbering gets reset to one

Tags: luatex, page-numbering

I am using report class for a document. I need to add a declaration before abstract. When I set `\thispagestyle{plain}` it resets the counter to one. How can I have the page numbering to get continued?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec,ragged2e}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in}
\title{foo}
\author{choo}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DEC}
\centering CHOGEGNAP\\
\justifying
\lipsum[5]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! And thank for providing a MWE. We often have to prod people into making them. A bit of experimentation reveals that `\thispagestyle{plain}` has no bearing on the page numbering (as expected), only on whether the page number is printed or not, and how. You can see this from the log file: Each `[1]` indicates a page numbered 1 being shipped out. However, the `abstract` environment does execute `\titlepage`, which resets the page number. I am not sure how best to get around that, but offer this insight to anyone who wants to try.

Comment: When you delete `\thispagestyle{plain}`the page number is unchanged as Harald Hanche-Olsen noted. So, the problem does not come from adding this macro.

Comment: when I did `\setcounter{page}{2}` it changes on that page but content page remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec,ragged2e}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in}
\title{foo}
\author{choo}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DEC}
\centering CHOGEGNAP\\
\justifying
\lipsum[5]
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \lipsum[5]
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sharing a solution is good. Explaining it is better.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can accept it as such. Can you do that so we can consider this question "closed?"